# Select en oracle que consulte los valores con diferentes combinaciones de campos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo la siguiente tabla y quiero hacer una consulta en oracle que me retorne los regitros con combinaciones de campos.
Quiero traer los registros en donde se combinen los campos `G_COUNTRY_ID` y `GF_CALL_CHANNEL_ID`.

Por ejemplo quiero traer los registros en donde

`(G_COUNTRY_ID='CO' AND GF_CALL_CHANNEL_ID='WEB')` y `(G_COUNTRY_ID='ES' AND GF_CALL_CHANNEL_ID='GEM')`

[image: Esta es mi base de datos]

Y al hacer esa consulta solo me debería retornar esto:
[image: Esto es lo que quiero de respuesta]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya vi cómo, solo pongo las combinaciones en paréntesis y agrego un `or`

```sql
SELECT GF_APP_MGR_USER_ID, G_COUNTRY_ID, GF_APPLICATION_ID, 
GF_SEGMENT_ID, GF_CALL_CHANNEL_ID 
FROM FORMACION.T_O43T_ADMIN_USERS 
WHERE (G_COUNTRY_ID='CO' AND GF_CALL_CHANNEL_ID='WEB') 
OR (G_COUNTRY_ID='ES' AND GF_CALL_CHANNEL_ID='GEM')
```